# Google Ads API - How to get all campaigns that are created via google ads api (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to find the total cost of google ads campaigns that are created via a particular manager account or via google ads api.

I tried the change event query where it gives me all the campaigns created via google ads but the issue is with `change_event.change_date_time`. It requires this filter otherwise it throws an error. Because of this filter, I am only getting campaigns that are created in this specific time period, but I need all campaigns.

```
SELECT
  change_event.campaign
FROM change_event
WHERE
  campaign.status != 'REMOVED'
  AND change_event.change_date_time >= '${from_date}'
  AND change_event.change_date_time <= '${to_date}'
  AND change_event.client_type = 'GOOGLE_ADS_API'
ORDER BY change_event.change_date_time ASC
LIMIT 10000
```

Reference Link: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v9/change_event_query_builder

Comment: Why can't you just set a date range all the way back to when the account was first opened?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `change_event` can only go retrieve data up to 30 days old ([see here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/change_event)).

I've tried building a query that could get that information but using `FROM campaign` but it seems like only `change_event` has access to how a campaign was created.

A possible solution would be to create multiple from/to date on 30-day cycles, starting from the account creation date.

Otherwise, you can use [`change status`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/change_status) for a slightly larger window of 90 days, with the limitation that you can't filter by `change_event.client_type = 'GOOGLE_ADS_API'`, using simply `change_status.resource_status = 'ADDED'` instead.

```sql
SELECT
  change_status.campaign
FROM change_status
WHERE
  campaign.status != 'REMOVED'
AND change_status.resource_status = 'ADDED'
AND change_status.last_change_date_time >= '${from_date}'
AND change_status.last_change_date_time <= '${to_date}'
ORDER BY change_status.last_change_date_time ASC
LIMIT 10000
```